# In OpenMP is there a way to know if we are inside an omp single region?

Tags: c++, openmp

Is there a way in OpenMP (4.5 and later) to know if we are inside an "omp single" region? For example there is the "omp_in_parallel()" function which checks if we are inside a parallel region. Is there a way to know if we are inside an "omp single" region?

Comment: What would you like to achieve? Could `omp_get_num_threads() == 1` be a sufficient check?

Comment: I need to check that a part of the code is executed only once, by one thread

Comment: I think what you want is not possible. However, the expected result in general cases is unclear to me. Indeed, OpenMp is not only based on the fork-join model anymore. What is the expected result in tasks executed possibly from other tasks recursively? Due to the way ICV works, two OpenMP threads can execute the same code in two different tasks (possibly with different ancestor tasks) but the two cannot get informations about the state of the other thread. In such a case, knowing if a code is in a single region does not make much sense. The same question apply with nested parallel regions.

Comment: @ynpos assuming the `single` is inside a parallel region, `omp_num_threads` will return the number of threads in the parallel region. Being inside an `omp single` does not affect that.